# Grouping in asp.net gridview?

Tags: asp.net, sorting, gridview, grouping, separator

I have an asp.net gridview in which I am showing a column of date, the date itself is coming from a sql database table, I have used sorting in that grid and it works perfectly when I click on date column but I want some kind of grouping based on date, like depicted below:

Default gridview look when sorted

21/07/2011

21/07/2011

25/07/2011

25/07/2011

27/07/2011

27/07/2011

What I want is:

21/07/2011

21/07/2011

---

25/07/2011

25/07/2011

---

27/07/2011

27/07/2011

I want some kind of separator or blank row that separate groups based on dates, this way data will be more clearly visible. How can I achieve this ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The ListView has grouping like this out of the box.